# Where should php's "require" and "include" be placed on a php page

Tags: php

I have a question for my own clarification.

I have seen includes and requires used on files that have both html and php code integrated alongside. On some of these files, there is already pre-existing php code on top of the requires and includes.

Is there any impact with regards to where these requires and includes are being called even if the functionality that needs them is defined underneath them?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's really low quality and shows no effort at all

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was under the impression that stackoverflow was a place where you could get information and improve your knowledge about programming. Your statement just sounds elitist and did not help me learn anything regarding my question at all.

Comment: don't take this personal, the comment is part of Stack Overflow's review process and it applies to questions abut to be closed, like yours. Your question is out of Stack Overflow's scope, and the answer is widely available by just doing a search on any search engine. Please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to make a good question so you can get advantage of this great resource

Comment: Not taking it personally at all. I've tried this question on google and researching on it for several hours. After not getting answers that helped me with my question on several leads, I tried stackoverflow. I don't want to spend 4 or more hours looking for answers especially when there are venues with which to get those answers from. This would be very impractical and time-inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does matter where you put your include files.. for e.g.

on your page you have header(top), body(middle) and footer(bottom)

and almost always header and footer are same for all the other pages of website.

you can create header.include.php and footer.include.php file and put header html code in header and footer html code in footer.include.php.

consider this
header.include.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

footer.include.php

```
    </body>
</html>
```

and you main file index.php

```
include 'header.include.php';

include 'footer.include.php':
```

so it should be in this order so header loads first and then footer in order for browser to understand you code.

Most of time it's on the top of page and this included files contain imp function which needs to be loaded first in order to make following code of the page work.

visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp for more understanding.

hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Just place your "requires" and "includes" at top of the code. That will help you, understanding and reading your code. (And even for others)